# How to create repeating sequence of values along a column in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want the data to be values repeating every 8 times like in the attached screenshot.

I used the formula =ROUNDUP(ROW()/8,0) but it only works properly when the formula begins in the first row. Since I need to use the repeating data multiple times within a column when I copy-paste the formula, it doesn't start with "1". The following image is what I want. What am I doing wrong?

What formula would let me simply copy-paste it at any point in a column and drag down to create a set of sequentially repeating numbers starting from 1 repeating 8 times each?

[image: Excel screenshot]

Comment: `=ROUNDUP(ROW(A1)/8,0)`

Comment: Or: `=INT(ROW(A8)/8)`

Comment: I think you want to be able to copy the a cell within a current range and paste it in a new cell and expect it to restart from `1`? Which means you want a formula to use `ROW()` but able to always restart from `1`. I think it might not be possible. `Vba` may be able to overwrite the paste result within a specific column to one of the formulas provided by BigBen or JvdV then you can drag it down to get the same sequence.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is restarting at `1` on random rows

If you fill the first 8 rows with `1`s, then use the following formula:

```
=IF(A8="",1,IF(COUNTIF(A1:A8,A8)<8,A8,A8+1))
```

and drag down.

Then to restart the count at `1`, clear one line above the one where the count restarts (as per your screen cap)